# Angular/Typescript: arrays in typescript changing when an independent element got changed

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

Why my array element is getting updated when another variable which gets a copy of one of the item in the array is updated?

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3tgp7h

(check AppComponent)

Code:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  materials: Material[] = [];
  material: Material;

  ngOnInit(){
    
    this.materials = [
      {
        name: 'One',
        price:10,
      },
      {
        name: 'Two',
        price:10,
      },
      {
        name: 'Three',
        price:10,
      },
    ];

    this.material = this.materials.find(mat => mat.name === 'One');

    console.log('material ones price in the array: '+this.materials.find(mat => mat.name === 'One').price )

    //Update (single) material object

    this.material.price = 20;

   // below is displaying 20. but i didn't update array
   // why is this happening?
    console.log('material ones price in the array after update: '+this.materials.find(mat => mat.name === 'One').price )
  }
}

export interface Material {
  name: string;
  price: number;
}
```

Comment: You are getting a reference to an element in the array. So you are basically editing the item in the array.

Comment: Deep Cleaning for array comes to rescue here !!

Comment: [pass by reference vs pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will give you reference of that object

```
this.material = this.materials.find(mat => mat.name === 'One');
```

And that's why it's updating the value in source array.

You can create a deep clone as:

```
let foundObj = this.materials.find(mat => mat.name === 'One');
if(foundObj) {
    foundObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foundObj));
}
this.material = foundObj;
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify());` is not perfact for all case and not recommended by community

Comment: Thanks. Suggesting "community recommended" approach for deep cloning would help